# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray Fix in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge csv file that is about 200 GB. I tried using chunks to run them in chunks so my vscode wouldn't crash. The goal is to find how many unique variables there are in the column "queryId".

This is what I did.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_df = []
    for df in pd.read_csv("file", chunksize = 10000):
       ids = df.queryId.unique()
       main_df.append(ids)
    uniqueids = pd.unique(main_df)
    number_of_uniqueids = len(uniqueids)
    print("Number of Unique Ids:", number_of_uniqueids)
```

The code ended up with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.
I think this is because I have a bunch of stuff that look something like "array(['553b52fb-4575-47b9-a67e-9bf53d03cc93'], dtype=object)" in my main_df list. How do I fix this to have my main_df list to just have the queryIds, which is something like "553b52fb-4575-47b9-a67e-9bf53d03cc93"?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace to you question ?

Comment: `df.queryId.unique()` returns a NumPy array. NumPy arrays of possibly variable lengths are appended to `main_df`. And `pd.unique()` takes in a 1D array input not ndarray.

Comment: You can try to flatten `main_df` before using `pd.unique()`

Comment: @ljmc just did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from `pd.unique(main_df)`, as the input cannot be a multi-dimensional array but one-dimensional. I got the following stack trace.

```
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The below code does not throw the error. Here, I have appended the unique ids in each chunk into a single NumPy array using [`append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). Tested on a sample CSV as well.

```
import numpy as np

main_df = np.array([])
for df in pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv", chunksize = 100):
    ids = df.total_bedrooms.unique()
    main_df = np.append(main_df,ids)
uniqueids = pd.unique(main_df.flatten())
number_of_uniqueids = len(uniqueids)
print("Number of Unique Ids:", number_of_uniqueids)
```

Output:

```
Number of Unique Ids: 1848
```